# Derive an Approximation for Random Walk Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, continuity, random-walk, stirling-numbers

I have a problem that I'm unsure how to solve with a method suggested by the question hint.

> **Problem**
>   A particle takes a random walk on the integers, starting at 0. At each step it advances to the next integer (move to the right) with probability 1/4 or goes back to the previous integer (moves to the left) with probability 3/4. Let the position of the particle after $n$ moves be $X_n$. Derive an asymptotic equivalent for $P(X_{2n} = 0)$. (Hint: use Stirling's approximation.)

As you can tell it is a very basic random walk problem, but I'm not familiar with Stirling's method. It seems to be using $In(x)$ integral to derive a curvature approx. for the probability. I think I have to use this equation at some point:
$$In(x)!=nIn(n)-n+1, Interval(1,n)$$
Would like to have some guidance on applying it to the problem.

Comment: The distribution of where you are at after 2n steps is a binomial distribution, for which you can use Stirling to obtain asymptotic estimates.

Comment: (Concretely: you want to know the probability of n failures and n successes in 2n trials, where a success happens with probability 1/4.)

Comment: Someone deleted his answer, which made perfect sense. I hope he will come back to provide the explanation again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{2n} =0) = \mathrm{Binomial}\left(n;2n,\frac{1}{4}\right) = \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^n$$
Using Stirling's formula 
$$ \binom{2n}{n} \approx \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$$
So $$  \mathbb{P}(X_{2n} =0) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$$